# Access front end by the back end of boost meta state machine

Tags: c++, boost, boost-msm

For some reasons, I can't setup the parameter of the state machine by constructor
So I would like to access the public member function of the meta state machine by the
back end. That is, I want something like

```
typedef msm::back::state_machine<player_> player;

player p;
p.get_front_end(); //get the address of the front end
p.get_front_end().set_param(34) //call the member function of front end
```

Is this possible?Thanks

The other solution is pass the parameter into the state machine by Event.

```
p.process_event(open_theme(34));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The back-end inherits the front-end, so you can call set_param directly on p.

Comment: Thanks, it is easier than I thought.